# C# run application

Tags: c#

Does someone knows how can I run "IISRESET" from c# application as if as I would run it from the start->run ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
//process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\WINDOWS\system32\iisreset.exe";
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C iisreset /STOP";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: But Richard, this way you won't have to put the exact path to the exe file \WINDOWS\system32\iisreset.exe, which is good.

Answer (score 5):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("IISRESET.exe");
```

NOTE: You will need to provide correct path to `IISRESET` as a parameter. Above is just a sample code.

Answer (score 2):

```
Process iisreset = new Process();
iisreset.StartInfo.FileName = "iisreset.exe";
iisreset.StartInfo.Arguments = "computername";
iisreset.Start();
```

Your C# application might need specific permission to launch it.
`iisreset.exe` is located in the `windows\system32` folder.

- [MSDN: Process.Start Method](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx)

Comment: +1: On Vista, 2008 and later you will likely need to elevate (Run and Administrator).